# Azure Web App + Unity3d WebGl Error: we need the wasm binary to be preloaded and set on Module['wasmBinary']

Tags: azure, unity-game-engine, iis, unity-webgl

I'm stored my Unity project on Web App Microsoft Azure, according to [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-deploying.html?_ga=2.232915158.994422719.1596641052-1980584500.1594775150) and [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Webgl-Server-configuration-for-WebAssembly-streaming.html) documentation i've add in `Build` subfolder this one `web.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".unityweb" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".unityweb" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
            <remove fileExtension=".wasm" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".wasm" mimeType="application/wasm" />
        </staticContent>
        <rewrite>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="Append gzip Content-Encoding header">
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Content-Encoding" pattern=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="\.(unityweb|wasm)$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="gzip" />
                </rule>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

`successfully downloaded but not stored in the indexedDB cache due to the error: Error: indexedDB access denied UnityLoader.js:3 You can reduce your startup time if you configure your web server to host .unityweb files using gzip compression.`

I will be very appreciate if you'll help me with it.

**UPDATED**

`abort("on the web, we need the wasm binary to be preloaded and set on Module['wasmBinary']. emcc.py will do that for you when generating HTML (but not JS)") at Error`

Comment: this error was raised by your browser. Make sure you're not using incognito mode

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio yes you are right i've updated the post because, now raise another error

Answer (score 0):

to resolve the issue open the chrome browser. go to  chrome://flags/#enable-webassembly .

Find the flag and turn it to Enable, and Relaunch Now.

[image]